# Identifying importance of each feature in deep model

Tags: deep-learning, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, prediction

I have a deep model and I want to figure out which feature has the maximum influence on predicted result. For this I train the model with all the features I think are important, during prediction I set all features `=0` one by one keeping the rest unchanged so I could figure out which is the least important of all. On predicting the results of these tampered test set on the trained model I get the same(changes at 5th-6th decimal place) F1 score, Recall and Precision.

Can some one explain me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This could mean that your features are heavily correlated. As a result, when you set one variable to 0, there is always another one that carries the same information. 
Try to set several features to 0 to see if you have the same issue. If yes, then it might be something else (maybe your code).

You might also be interested in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304380002002570), you'll find several methods to assess feature importance.

Comment: I have changed a few features simultaneously as you suggested and my results have varied (on 2nd decimal place). Just one more thing, I just realized most of the entries in my dataset are already `=0` and therefore the results don't vary as much as they should. What value shall I set my features to that signify removing it other than 0. Any idea?

Comment: What about adding random noise to the input (mean=0, std=feature's std)?

Comment: that appears a nice idea! I will try this. Another query, why you suggest `(mean=0, std=feature's std)`?

Comment: I wasnt sure if your features are normalized or have the same value range. If some of them vary between 0 and 1000 and others between 0 and 1, a random noise with variance 1 won't have the same effect on them. That's why I suggested a different noise variance depending on the feature.